# Elements in ion-nav-bar unclickable, non functioning

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating an ionic map application and trying to add a toggle-able searchbar to my nav-bar. Everything I add to the left side of my navbar via ion-nav-buttons side="left" (search icon, input bar) cannot be clicked/focused on. Strangely, I can click on areas of those elements if they spill out off of the navbar. Code and test images below:

```
<body ng-app="radar">
    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-positive" ng-controller="MenuController" delegate-handle="navBar" align-title="center">
                <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
                    </button>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
                <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                    <div class="searchBar">
                        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon searchButton" ng-click="newSearch()"></i>
                        <div class="searchTxt" ng-show="showSearch">
                            <div class="bgdiv"></div>
                            <div class="bgtxt">
                                <input type="text" class="searchInput" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="search">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-content ng-controller="MapController" class="mapCanvas has-header">
                <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
                <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
                <button id="GeoButton" ng-click="geoLocate()"><i class="icon ion-android-locate"></i></button>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu-content>

  <!-- RIGHT SLIDE MENU -->      
        <ion-side-menu class="rightMenu" side="right">
            <header class="bar bar-dark bar-header rightMenuHeader">
                <h1 class="title">Right Menu</h1>
            </header>
          <ion-content class="has-header">
              <ion-nav-view name="RIGHT MENU"></ion-nav-view>
              <div class="button-bar logReg">
                  <a class="button" ng-click="">Login</a>
                  <a class="button" ng-click="">Register</a>
              </div>
          </ion-content>
      </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>
```

and some CSS:

```
.searchBar {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}

.searchBar .icon {
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
.searchBar .searchTxt {
  left: 55px;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  color: white;
}

.searchIcon {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.searchBar .searchTxt > .bgdiv {
  background-color: darkBlue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.searchBar .searchTxt > .bgtxt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.searchBar .searchTxt input {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right:5px;
}

.rightMenu {
  background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
}
```

[image: How it should look]

[image: Messy version showing situations in which I can interact with elements]

Comment: Did you managed to solve it already?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you should have a controller named 'MenuController' in your www/js/controllers.js file with a function newSearch().

Here is what I'm using in my controllers.js file to capture button click in the navbar with the controller 'NavCtrl' and the function .getPhoto()

```
.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {
$scope.getPhoto = function() {
    //alert("button clicked");
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI) {
  }, function(err) {
    console.err(err);
  });
}
```